# Jquery Autocomplete reading a CSV File

Tags: jquery, csv, autocomplete

I need to display a record from csv file in table while using Jquery Autocompletion. Finally, I wish to combine these 2 scripts in one :

[Autocomplete With HTML5 & jQuery](https://designshack.net/articles/javascript/create-a-simple-autocomplete-with-html5-jquery/) & 
[Reading a CSV File Using jQuery](http://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/reading-csv-file-using-jquery/)

I don't want to display all records, but only the record requested in autocompletion field.

I don't know how to do it.

Many Thanks !